# design issues in producer-consumer problem

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am working on a little multi-threading project.The system could be divided into 2 sub parts, A and B. the data flows from A to B.
A part keeps fetching raw data from outside world, do some transformation and and then generate thousands of new data, let's call it A_OUTPUT.
B part do some calculations based on each A_OUTPUT and then generate even more data, may be ten times the number of A_OUTPUT.

I am confused about how to synchronize the 2 parts.
My own design is to create a work queue as well as a lock protecting the queue between the two sub parts. Also create a event to indicate whether the work queue is empty or not.

A part consists multiple threads, each thread fetch data from outside and generate A_OUTPUT, each time a single A thread generate a A_OUTPUT, the thread obtain the queue lock, push the A_OUTPUT into the queue, release the lock, and then trigger the event.

B part consists a supervisor thread and several worker threads, the supervisor thread was first blocked on the event. after the event was triggered, the supervisor thread lock the queue, fetch all A_OUTPUTS of the queue, release the lock, dispatch A_OUTPUTS to worker threads, and then wait on the event again.

The problem of this design is obvious, the supervisor thread of B will be racing with multiple threads of A to win the queue lock. maybe when B finally own the lock, there was already ten or more A_OUTPUTs in the queue, and the most aged A_OUTPUT was generated a long time ago. I want each A_OUTPUT to be processed as fast as possible.

I know I could divide the work queue into several smaller queues or add more B supervisor threads into the lock battle to shorten the average time each A_OUTPUT wait before it get processed. but might there exist a more appropriate design?

And another question, does there exists any paradigm or design pattern for different purpose multi-thread programs?

Comment: There are 2 concepts involved here: queue locking and synchronizing. I am not proficient in C++, but java deals with these two concepts in the implementation of this queue object, called 'Blocking Queue': http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: How do you intend to control the number of B worker threads created, couldn't that just spiral out of control. "fetch all A_OUTPUTS of the queue" doesn't sound like a good idea if processing of A_OUTPUTS is going to take time, since we are looking at unbounded thread creation. I think we need some kind of a threadpool here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rather classical problem that is well described in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem)

I can recommend following approach:

Synchronize access to the queue by [mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.mutex). keep two [condition variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable), one to signal that queue is not full (you need to handle cases when `Producer` produces more data than `Consumer` can consume) and another one to signal that queue has any data.

`Producer` checks if queue is not full. If full - waits for condition "not full", otherwise produces some data, puts it into queue, notifies "has data" condition.

`Consumer` checks if queue has any data, consumes it and notifies "not full" condition

Also you can use lock-free queue for better performance. Check [TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) or recently announced **Boost.Lockless** (under review at the moment). By the way, using TBB the whole task is much simpler, just use their dispatcher and containers and forgot about 
explicit synchronization

Answer (score 1):

Like @thiton, I don't see the need for a supervisor thread - it seem like an unnecessary complication?

This seems to a question of flow-control as well as queue-design. Given what you seem to need, I would go for two producer-consumer queues and a limited number of A_OUTPUT instances.  I would create 1000, (say), A_OUTPUT instances and push them onto one P-C queue, forming a thread-safe object pool, at startup, (pool queue).  The A threads start, pop an A_OUTPUT from the pool and commence 'fetching raw data from outside world'.  When an A thread has got data in its A_OUTPUT, it pushes it onto another P-C queue, (comms queue).  A pool of B threads are waiting on the comms queue.  When an A_OUTPUT becomes available on the comms queue, a B thread will get it and process it.  When the B thread has finished with the data, is pushes the A_OUTPUT back onto the pool queue.  The A_OUTPUT instances therefore circulate around, carrying data from one end of the system to the other and then back to the start via the pool queue.

Designs like this allow flow-control across multiple threads/pools.  There is sufficient 'slack' in the queues to allow bursts of high load, but runaway threads/objects is not possible - if there is too much data flowing through, the A threads will find the pool empty and block on it until A_OUTPUT instances become available - when the are, the A threads will continue to fetch more data.

Such a system can be tuned at run time. Adding/removing threads from the A/B thread pools and increasing/decreasing the object pool depth is easy.

Oh - an you don't need complex bounded P-C queues.  If each queue can hold the number of objects in the pool, that's enough - no more will ever be available.

Rgds,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You could control the queue age problem by limiting the queue size, like Andy T suggested.

In addition, if you drop the supervisor thread, your layout becomes much simpler. Have the threads of A acquire the mutex when they finish processing, put their item in the queue, and wait until the queue is empty enough to continue. Each consumer thread waits until an item in the queue is available, gets it and works with it.

Since there is a sufficiently close number of threads of A and B, starvation should be unlikely. Additionally, you should use methods such as pthread_cond_signal (instead of pthread_cond_broadcast), which only wake up a single thread from each side, minimizing the number of races.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article here that may help:
http://drdobbs.com/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=184401751

(Oops, just noticed this is an old thread it was just the answer was edited an hour ago.)